# Exploit grouped features for a classification problem

Tags: classification, bayesian, naive-bayes

I've got a dataset of 100.000 labelled vectors, each one with a set of 100 *binary* features: $$F = \{ f_{1}, f_{2}, ..., f_{100} \}.$$

I am able to build a Bernoulli Naive Bayes classifier for guessing the label for a new instance vector.

By the way, I know that these features may be grouped (according to some criteria) in 5 groups of 20: $$F' = \{ f_{1,1}, f_{1,2}, ..., f_{1,20}, f_{2,1}, ..., f_{2,0}, ..., f_{5,1}, ..., f_{5,20} \}.$$

In which case (and how) I could exploit this grouping?

Comment: i think it'll hard to get a particularly useful answer without more context since a "grouping" can imply so many different things. If you want to use fewer features you could try doing feature selection at the group level. With 100k data points you could probably just do a best subsets as that's $2^5-1$ models, but you could also use something like the grouped lasso. Alternatively, do you have any extra info that can help you derive new features within each block? Are there interactions or XORs or anything like that that you can add in? That could be very helpful for your model